# Flat List renderItem is called when there is any state change not related to flatlist data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

```
    showScrollToTopView = () => {
        const { showScrollToTopView } = this.state
        const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
        if (this.scrolledValue >= 2 * DEVICE_HEIGHT - HEADER_HEIGHT && !showScrollToTopView) {
            this.setState({
                showScrollToTopView: true
            })
        } else if (this.scrolledValue <= DEVICE_HEIGHT - HEADER_HEIGHT && showScrollToTopView) {
            this.setState({
                showScrollToTopView: false
            })
        }
    }

    getKeyExtractor = (item, index) => {
        return `${get(item, '_id', '')}`
    }

    renderFeedCardComponent = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <CommunityCardComponent
                cardType={'QUESTION_CARD'}
                questionData={item}
                onClickOptions={this.onClickOptions}
                questionPopupOptionsKey={QUESTION_CARD_OPTIONS}
                onLabelPressed={this.onLabelClicked}
            />
        )
    }

<FlatList
                
                            onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: context.scrollYValue } } }], {
                                useNativeDriver: true,
                                listener: ({ nativeEvent }) => {
                                    const yOffsetValue = get(nativeEvent, 'contentOffset.y', 0)
                                    this.scrolledValue = yOffsetValue
                                    {
                                        this.showScrollToTopView()
                                    }
                                    if (getScrolledPosition) {
                                        getScrolledPosition(yOffsetValue)
                                    }
                                }
                            })}
                            refreshControl={
                                <RefreshControl
                                    refreshing={shouldRefresh}
                                    progressViewOffset={HEADER_HEIGHT}
                                    onRefresh={() => {
                                        handleNetworkAvailableEvent(this.onRefresh)
                                    }}
                                />
                            }
                            scrollEventThrottle={16}
                            ref={(ref) => {
                                if (ref) {
                                    this.flatListRef = ref
                                    if (getFlatListRef) {
                                        getFlatListRef(ref)
                                    }
                                    context.addFlatListRef(this.flatListRef, uniqueKey)
                                }
                            }}
                             renderItem={this.renderFeedCardComponent}
                            keyExtractor={this.getKeyExtractor}
                            onMomentumScrollEnd={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                                const { contentOffset } = nativeEvent
                                if (contentOffset.y === 0) {
                                    context.flatListRef.forEach((item) => {
                                        if (item.key !== uniqueKey) {
                                            item.value.scrollToOffset({
                                                offset: 0,
                                                animated: false
                                            })
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }}
                            listKey={moment().valueOf().toString()}
                        />
```

Whenever my state changes the flatlist render Item is getting called. I have printed some logs while developing. Now I am using key extractor then why is my flatlist render item getting called. Can explain why is this happening.Now whenever my state changes my flatlist render Item is getting called. I have printed some log while doing development.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, the renderItem function is redefined everytime your component is rendered (which happens every time your state is changed).
You should define a function in your class component and call it in the render.

It is also true for the other functionnal props of your flatlist (like keyExtractor, onScroll...)

Comment: I have updated my component and converted my renderItem and key extractor into functions. But still the same thing is happening

Answer (score 0):

When there is a state change, component gets rerendered. When a component rerenders, it renders its children again, even if their props have not changed. So if you have a component like:

```
function Component() {
  // Some code
  return <AnotherComponent />
}
```

`AnotherComponent` will be rendered everytime there is a state change in `Component`, even though its got no props.

To avoid rerendering in this case you can use [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

You could use composing components to render less in some cases:
In the following component , `App` component, `AnotherComponent` would not be rerendered everytime `Component` is rerendered:

```
// App.js

<Component>
  </AnotherComponent>
</Component>
```

But if `App` component rerenders, it would render both `Component` and `AnotherComponent` to again.

Comment: Since flatlist uses the key extractor then it should not call the renderItem if the data is same

Comment: @rohitgarg As far as I understood you can either use `React.PureComponent`, if your component is rendered because its parent is rendered, Or if you have a custom condition you can use `shouldComponentUpdate`, but it react does not guarantee using it would prevent rendering.